# All else equal, why would switching from Glorot_Uniform to He initializers cause my loss function to blow up?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, keras

In a recent Kaggle competition regarding plant pathology, I trained a VGG16 model that resulted in a loss function starting at ~1.8 and eventually converging around ~0.5 for my validation set.

[image: Working VGG16 with default initializer, Glorot Uniform]

I wanted to experiment with the Kaiming He initializer given the number of relu activation layers in a VGG16 model. So I created a custom initializer in Keras to implement He initialization. (Yes, I know He init is already implemented in TF2.3.0, but I'm sticking to TF2.0 and I want to learn how to write custom inits).

To my surprise, switching from Glorot to He caused my loss function to explode, going from ~1.8 to **1e18+**.

[image: Model blowing up after switching to He initializer]

I don't know what to make of this... Both initializers should be choosing small, normally distributed values with

- std_dev_glorot = sqrt(6/(fan_in+fan_out)) and
- std_dev_he = sqrt(2/(fan_in))

Here's my question: all else being equal, **why would a working model with Glorot Uniform blow up by switching to He initializations?**

My suspicions:

- the lack of including the 'fan_out' denominator in He formula is resulting in bigger values at the far side of the Normal distribution
- am I supposed to use He initialization for some layers only?  (Currently, I put it on every layer with relu activation.)
- do I have a faulty implementation of my custom funciton?  Perhaps the shape is wrong and it's not dividing by the appropriate number?

This is the notebook I used to train and report results:

```
#%%
import os, sys
homePath = os.path.expanduser('~')
plantsDatasetPath = os.path.join(homePath, 'datasets', 'plant-pathology-2020-fgvc7')
print(plantsDatasetPath)

SrcPath = os.path.join(homePath, "plant_pathology", "src")
sys.path.append(SrcPath)

OutputPath = os.path.join(homePath, "plant_pathology", "output")
print(OutputPath)

from utils.get_weights_for_class_imbalance import getWeightsPerClass
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from utils.clr_callback import CyclicLR
import tensorflow as tf
from callbacks.training_monitor import TrainingMonitor
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from datetime import datetime

#%%

from datasets.csv_multiclass_loader import CsvDatasetLoader
from pre_processors.aspect_aware_pre_processor import AspectAwarePreProcessor

awpp = AspectAwarePreProcessor(224,224)
dataset_loader = CsvDatasetLoader(preprocessors=[awpp])
(data, labels) = dataset_loader.load(maxRecords=None)
orig_data = data[:]

#%%
norm_data = orig_data / np.amax(orig_data)
print(norm_data.shape)

(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(norm_data,
                                                  labels,
                                                  test_size=0.25,
                                                    random_state=42,
                                                  stratify=labels)

weights = getWeightsPerClass(trainY)

#%%

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
aug = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30, width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")

#%%

tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
pid = os.getpid()
from models.vgg16_with_he_initializer import vgg16_with_he_initializer
from models.vgg16 import Vgg16
INPUT_SIZE = (224,224,3)
output_classes=4

## Bad Version
mn = "vgg16_with_he_initializer"
model = vgg16_with_he_initializer.build(*INPUT_SIZE, output_classes)

## Good Version
# mn = "vgg16"
# model = Vgg16.build(*INPUT_SIZE, output_classes)

epochs = 150
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 32

opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.1)
clr_triangular = CyclicLR(mode='exp_range',gamma=0.99994, base_lr=learning_rate/10, max_lr=learning_rate, step_size=8*batch_size)  

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), 'accuracy'], optimizer=opt)

tensorboardLogDir = os.path.join(homePath, "plant_pathology", "logs", "scalars")
expLogDir = os.path.join(tensorboardLogDir, f'{mn}_{w}x{h}x{d}_weights_pid_{pid}_', datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=expLogDir, histogram_freq=1)

#%%

H = model.fit_generator(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=batch_size),
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // batch_size,
    class_weight=weights,
    callbacks=[clr_triangular, tensorboard_callback],
    epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

If I run this with "Good Version", I use a VGG16 model, like this:

```
class Vgg16:
  @staticmethod
  def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1

    model.add(Input(shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(units=classes, activation="softmax"))

    return model
```

If I run this with "Bad Version", I use a VGG16 model with a custom kernel_initializer I wrote to implement Kaiming He, et al., initialization weights, like this:

```
zerosInitializer = tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()

def my_KaimingHe_initializer(shape, dtype=tf.float32):
  stddev = tf.sqrt(2. / (shape[0]))
  return tf.random.normal(shape=shape, stddev=stddev, dtype=dtype)

class vgg16_with_he_initializer:
  @staticmethod
  def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1

    model.add(Input(shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same",
                     activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same",
                     activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu", kernel_initializer=my_KaimingHe_initializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=classes, activation="softmax"))
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd still like to get an answer from another pro, but it seems I found a workaround in the meantime that leads me to believe that the culprit is my custom initializer implementation of He's weights.

Looking at Tensorflow Core 2.3.0 implementation of the He initializer, it seems we can implement He's distribution using the VarianceScaling function in TF 2.0.0 if we use certain parameters. See here:

````
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense, Input
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf

zerosInitializer = tf.keras.initializers.Zeros()

HeInitializer = tf.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling(
    scale=2.0, mode='fan_in', distribution='truncated_normal', seed=None
)

class vgg16_with_he_initializer:
  @staticmethod
  def build(width, height, depth, classes):
    model = Sequential()
    inputShape = (height, width, depth)
    chanDim = -1

    model.add(Input(shape=inputShape))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same",
                     activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same",
                     activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu", kernel_initializer=HeInitializer,
                     bias_initializer=zerosInitializer))
    model.add(Dense(units=classes, activation="softmax"))

    return model

```
````